# Anchor tag not filling height and width

Tags: html, css, image, height, width

I am trying to create the gallery section on a test site, I have made the gallery but for some reason the a tags won't fill the height and width of the images at all, they all seem to collapse into the first quarter of the first line of images.

Here is the code:  (Actually with this code the a tags are taking the height and width but the images are stacking on top of each other)

HTML

```
<section class="portfolio">
<h1>&mdash; PORTFOLIO &mdash;</h1>
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img4.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img5.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img6.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img7.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img8.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img9.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href=#"">
    <img src="img/img10.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img11.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img12.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.portfolio {
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  left: 80px;
}

.portfolio h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family:'Poiret One', cursive;
}

.gallery img {
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    height: 230px;
    width: 330px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.gallery a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I'm probably doing something horribly wrong but I can't work it out!

Thanks in advance.

https://jsfiddle.net/utaLy18j/1/

Comment: It would be good if you provide a [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: check once  by removing float from img and using display:block

Comment: @Benjamin Done.. I think! Thanks

Comment: @RITESHARORA Had no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing this.

remove the `float:left` on `.gallery img`. and then add `display:inline-block` on `.gallery img` and `.gallery`

```css
.portfolio {
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  left: 80px;
}

.portfolio h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.gallery{
  display:inline-block;
}

.gallery img {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 230px;
    width: 330px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.gallery a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section class="portfolio">
<h1>&mdash; PORTFOLIO &mdash;</h1>
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img4.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img5.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img6.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img7.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img8.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img9.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href=#"">
    <img src="img/img10.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img11.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img12.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
</section>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No worries. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

what I can assume that you want the images are display in a grid manner, if so the below code will help :

```
.gallery {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/utaLy18j/9/) here.

Please let me know if it works for you.